# How to identify which lines/polygons intersect when using raster data in R

Tags: raster, gdal, r, gdal-rasterize

We would like to merge vector and raster data to a common spatial grid. For example, suppose we have a vector file of roads; we'd like to know which roads intersect which cells in the grid. The image below provides a toy example, as well as the data we'd like to recover. The numbers on the top left corner of each cell is the cell ID, and the different colors represent the different roads that were rasterized. The yellow-orange represents road 2 (vertical line) and green represents road 1 (diagonal line).

[image: Raster sample]

[image: Tables]

While it's easy to solve this toy problem, we're working with global data and constructing a high resolution grid (~1km at equator). Given this scope and resolution, we need a computationally efficient solution. (Converting the grid to a shapefile, for example, using a spatial merge is not an attractive solution.)

Our initial approach to merging vector data to our spatial grid involved rasterizing the shapefile using common extents and resolution. Using the gdal_rasterize function, we could burn into the raster cells the feature identifiers associated with feature (e.g., each road in our data). **However, in instances where two features fall within the same raster cell, only one feature ID is retained.**

From the toy example above, in the cell containing both roads, we would only retain one of the road IDs after rasterizing instead of both the roads as shown in Table A. However, we want to retain all the roads and retrieve Table B. This way the table will let us know that there were two unique roads intersecting in this particular cell. Note: What we are currently getting is Table A, but we want to get something like Table B, which was manually created for demonstration. The column "val" indicates the road ID. For instance row 2 of Table B would represent road 2 in cell 2. Row 3 of Table B would represent road 1 in cell 2. Hence, the repetition in cell 2.

We've included a small but reproducible example here:
Note

1. You will need to create a directory called temp in your desktop.
2. We want to use our own rasterize function using gdal_rasterize shown in the code as we will be working with larger data sets and it is faster than using the raster package.

   ```
      ###################
      ## Load packages ##
      ###################
      pkgs <- c("rgdal", "rgeos", "raster", "data.table", "dplyr")
      sapply(pkgs, require, character.only = TRUE)

      #####################
      ## Create toy data ##
      #####################
      df <- rbind(c(1,1), c(4,4),c(3,1), c(3,4))

      coord_1 <- Line(rbind(c(1,1), c(4,4)))
      coord_2 <- Line(rbind(c(3,1), c(3,4)))

      l1 <- Lines(list(coord_1), ID = "road1")
      l2 <- Lines(list(coord_2), ID = "road2")

      Sl <- SpatialLines(list(l1, l2))

      df <- data.frame(len = sapply(1:length(Sl), function(i) gLength(Sl[i, ])))
      rownames(df) <- sapply(1:length(Sl), function(i) Sl@lines[[i]]@ID)

      toy.lines <- SpatialLinesDataFrame(Sl, data = df)
      toy.lines@data$polygon_id <- 1:nrow(toy.lines@data)

      # output shapefile
      setwd("~/Desktop/temp")
      writeOGR(toy.lines, ".", "toylines", driver="ESRI Shapefile")

      ####################
      ## gdal_rasterize ##
      ####################
      # rasterize function using gdal_rasterize
      Rasterize <- function(shp_dir, shp_fname, burn, output_wd,
                     gdal_cmd = "/Library/Frameworks/GDAL.framework/Versions/Current/Programs/gdal_rasterize",
                     config = "--config GDAL_CACHEMAX 2000",
                     compress = "-co compress=LZW",
                     extents = "-te 1 1 4 4",
                     resolution = "-tr 2 -2 -tap",
                     datatype = "-ot Int16") {

      new_fname <- gsub("shp$", "tif", shp_fname)

      shp_file <- paste0(shp_dir, "/", shp_fname)
      dest_file <- paste0(output_wd, "/", new_fname)

      cmd <- paste(gdal_cmd, config, burn, extents, 
              resolution, datatype, compress, 
              shp_file, dest_file)

      # Reporting results:
      cat("Saved", dest_file, "\n")

      return(system(cmd))
      }

      ####################
      ## table function ##
      ####################

      RasterToDT <- function(raster_file){
      values <- getValues(raster_file)
      data.table(cell = 1:length(values), val = values)
      }


      ############################
      ## Rasterize our toy data ##
      ############################
      Rasterize(
      shp_dir = "~/Desktop/temp",
      shp_fname = "toylines.shp",
      burn = "-a polygon_id -init -1", #encode -1 for cell with no element
      output_wd = "~/Desktop/temp")

      # Output table
      r <- raster("~/Desktop/temp/toylines.tif")
      dt_toylines <- RasterToDT(r)

      dt_toylines
   ```

Comment: Should cell 2 occur only once in Table B, with a value of 2?

Comment: That would correspond to Table A which describes the raster shown. Our goal is to determine all features that intersect a given cell. Hence, we want cell 2 to occur twice in our table B encoding both roads 1 and 2.

Comment: Oh I see, val is count in A but ID in B.  This is my candidate answer, but I can't get the same results as you show here, perhaps because of different rules used by GDAL about glancing intersection of a line at a cell corner? https://gist.github.com/mdsumner/642d5d06dd7c84fe54833a67ae74a4c4

Comment: Both table A and table B is using val for the road ID (there is no count involved). What we are currently getting from our toy example is table A and what we want is table B. If you look at the sample raster, road 1 and road 2 intersect at cell 2. Table A tells us that at cell 2 there is road 2 (val: 2), but doesn’t show that there is also road 1 (val: 1) in cell 2. Table B, which we want, repeats cell 2 twice to show both road 1 and road 2. Row 2 of Table B represents road 2 in cell 2. Row 3 of Table B represents road 1 in cell 2. I hope this helps clarify the issue.

Comment: Best help would be R code to produce the plot you see. I've done what I think it is in that Gist.

Comment: The output you created looks to be working except for the second to last row which outputs line: 1, cell: 4. There's only line 2 in cell 4.

Answer (score 2):

I made an answer with your toy lines but not with gdal (easy enough to change if you like). I decided to make a blank raster, presumably of which you know the extent? and then populate the table using extract:

```
# make the blank raster, the extents and resolution of which are up to you.
# the cells are numbered 1 to ncell (starting in the top left in R)
r <- raster(xmn=0,xmx=4,ymn=0,ymx=4,res=c(2,2))
r[] <- 1:ncell(r)

# make your toy.lines as above, except i've thrown in a 3rd to be daring
# why do you have length?
df <- rbind(c(1,1), c(4,4),c(3,1), c(3,4))

coord_1 <- Line(rbind(c(1,1), c(4,4)))
coord_2 <- Line(rbind(c(3,1), c(3,4)))
coord_3 <- Line(rbind(c(0,1), c(4,1)))

l1 <- Lines(list(coord_1), ID = "road1")
l2 <- Lines(list(coord_2), ID = "road2")
l3 <- Lines(list(coord_3), ID = "road3")

Sl <- SpatialLines(list(l1, l2, l3))

df <- data.frame(len = sapply(1:length(Sl), function(i) gLength(Sl[i, ])))
rownames(df) <- sapply(1:length(Sl), function(i) Sl@lines[[i]]@ID)

toy.lines <- SpatialLinesDataFrame(Sl, data = df)
toy.lines@data$polygon_id <- 1:nrow(toy.lines@data)

# use the extract function which will return a list, one element for every spatial line, 
# saying which cells it passes through. Named elements by id.
l <- extract(r,toy.lines)
names(l) <- toy.lines@data$polygon_id

# make a data table of cell ID and what line it touches, unlisting the list elements 
# and turning them into a long vector (and inserting that as a column)
cells.df <- data.table(cell=unlist(l),lineid=rep(as.numeric(names(l)),lapply(l, function(x) length(x))))
setkey(cells.df,cell)

# make a simple data table of all cell numbers (will enable us to keep NA cells)
all.cells <- data.table(cell=1:ncell(r))
setkey(all.cells,cell)

# merge by key. Data table orders by key and autopopulates NAs
final.df <- cells.df[all.cells]
```

That produces table B anyway. Unsure as to why it believes line 1 to pass through cell 4, but there you go.

[image]